# How can I embed the new GIFV format on my android app?

Tags: android, webview, gif

I would like to know if one of your could embed GIFV format into your app. I am trying to embed it using a webview but without success.

Actually GIFV format is closer to a video format than a gif.

Whatever suggestion would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After work around of this issue, I couldn't find a solution which could display GIFV format like a video.

But, my solution to this issue has been to use a webview using the same way that i was using to make able to load "gif" files and if you remove directly the "v" from the name of the file, you can show it as a .gif file.

Resuming, remove the "v" from the .gifv file name and display it as a .gif.

The way that i am injecting code to make able to display gifs into the webview is:

```
public void getContentWebView(String url, WebView webView)
{
    String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img src=\""+ url +"\"  width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```